# Application of l'hospital rule to exponential function

Tags: limits

The assignment I got is to solve the limit below using l'hospital's rule.

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{x-x^2}
$$

What I did was turn it into a quotient

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{e^{x}}{e^{x^2}}
$$

So now we have the indeterminate form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ and apply l'hospital's rule

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{e^{x}}{2 e^{x^2}x}
$$

I re-applied it a few times, but it appears that it cannot be solved this way.

My question is *how* can this be solved **with l'hospital's rule**? Please provide explanation or hint on how it can be worked out, I don't need a plain answer.

Comment: $x^2$ grows faster than $x$ thus the searched limit is $0$

Comment: the circumstance is that I have to apply this rule, even if there are easier ways of finding this limit

Comment: While Dr Sonnhard avoids the instruction that L'Hospitals Rule is to be used, I agree with him that this limit can be done much easier, as he indicated. This problem is not really suitable for Hospital, nor does it show the effectiveness of an otherwise beautiful rule. Why on earth does your teacher want you to do this problem with that rule? There are other (easier) ways to do this limit. I think it is legitimate to ask

Comment: Does the assignment make additional assumptions, e.g about the existence of the limit?

Comment: No mention about its existence. The only instruction given was "Use l’Hospital’s rule to compute the limits" and a couple of limits like above. To give some background, this is part of a first year calculus course for chemistry.

Answer (score 1):

While we do not use L'Hospital's Rule herein, one can proceed by simply noting that

$$e^{x-x^2}=e^{-(x-1/2)^2}e^{1/4}=\frac{e^{1/4}}{e^{(x-1/2)^2}}$$

Then, using the elementary inequality $e^x\ge 1+x$, we can write

$$0\le \frac{e^{1/4}}{e^{(x-1/2)^2}}\le \frac{e^{1/4}}{1+(x-1/2)^2}$$

whereupon application of the squeeze theorem yields the coveted limit

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}e^{x-x^2}=0$$

Comment: Ok, now I had to post mine too:) The more methods, the better...

Comment: Silly mistake, I deleted my post, I don't think it adds to the OP's problem

Comment: @imranfat No worry; I will delete this comments to avoid possible confusion of future readers.

Comment: Interestingly, the same problem is asked again under a different name, but I suspect by the same person. This time no Hospital Rule: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1936212/question-about-limit-with-exponents

Comment: @imranfat we probably attend the same university class and have the same homework assignment

Comment: @ttdijkstra That's quite a coincidence. Still makes me wonder...same problem, one with Hospital and then without. Do you think the teacher has realized that Hospital really makes no sense on a limit like that? Hospital's rule is supposed to make things easier, not the other way around....groetjes :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, there are much easier ways of finding the limit. However, if you have to use this calculation, let $a = \lim_{x \to \infty} e^{x-x^2}$. Your calculation gives you an algebraic equation you can use to determine exactly what the value of $a$ is.

Comment: I don't see how I can proceed to solve it using this information

Comment: You arrive at the expression $a=\frac{a}{2x}$ so what happens if $x$ goes to infinity?

Comment: You need to show that $a$ exists first before proceeding down this path.  ;-))

Comment: Yeah - but we can cheat a little in a first year calculus course :P

Comment: No, you cannot.

Comment: The fact that $a$ exists is trivial, because the limit is decreasing for $x > 1$.

Comment: I agree with Dr MV. This approach is not clean in spite of yielding the answer. And I wonder why the teacher wants the students to do this exercise with Hospital's rule.

Comment: The statement "the limit is decreasing for..." is nonsensical.  The limit is a single number.  Do you mean that $e^{x-x^2}$ is decreasing for $x>1$?  While true, how does this affect your analysis?  The function $1+1/x$ is decreasing and so is $e^{1-x}$, but the limits of these functions are not  zero.

Comment: My proof is incomplete because I'm only hinting at a solution. The function $1 + 1/x$ might not tend to zero, but the limit exists, *because* it is decreasing.

Comment: So, do you assert that all decreasing functions have limits?  I hope that you realize that such an assertion is easily refuted (e.g., $f(x)=-x$ is decreasing, but its limit diverges).   And your so-called "proof," is not a proof, nor a sketch of one.

Comment: In your example, $f(x) \to -\infty$. The proof I have in mind is perfectly rigorous, though I don't want to give it away to the person asking a question about his homework problem. Maybe with a bit more mathematical maturity and practice (or perhaps in just a less bitter mood), you'll be able to see a bigger picture, rather than picking at details which are meant to be filled in by the questioner so they can hone their understanding of analysis. Go take a break and grab a cup of tea, that always makes me feel better :) .